# Magento 2 - How to add the DateTime UI Component

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, ui-form, datetime

I want to add new field as datetime in CMS page section while adding new page, I found that magento using UI Component for it, so after digging I could able to add the date field by using below code but not able to add datetime field. Can anybody help on it.

Code for add date field:

```
<field name="start_date">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Go Live Start Date</item>
            <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">date</item>
            <item name="source" xsi:type="string">page</item>
            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">21</item>
            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">start_date</item>
            <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</field>
```

File we need to override to achieve:

```
vendor/magento/module-cms/view/adminhtml/ui_component/cms_block_form.xml
```

Comment: @sivakumar Whether my answer helped you?

Comment: Yes @SiarheyUchukhlebau, It helped alot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Magento 2 Show timepicker using UiComponent](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/154140/magento-2-show-timepicker-using-uicomponent)

Comment: @TejabhagavanKollepara Why you mark the question asked 9 months ago as the duplicate of the question asked 4 months ago?!

Answer (score 46, accepted):

To add the dateTime picker you should use the next directive inside the xml file:

```
<field name="start_date">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Go Live Start Date</item>
            <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">date</item>
            <item name="source" xsi:type="string">page</item>
            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">21</item>
            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">start_date</item>
            <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            </item>
            <item name="options" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="dateFormat" xsi:type="string">yyyy-MM-dd</item>
                <item name="timeFormat" xsi:type="string">HH:mm:ss</item>
                <item name="showsTime" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            </item>
            <item name="storeTimeZone" xsi:type="string">string</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</field>
```

**Important thing is the `showsTime` option.**

Result should look like this:

[image: date-time ui element result]

If you want to debug the UI element - use this command inside the browser console (on your page):

```
require('uiRegistry').get('index = start_date')
```

It returns your `date` element with all initial options and all possible functions:

[image: UI element object]

You can use them when you define the element (inside xml).

As additional info:

The `date` (also `dateTime`) element could be found here:

```
app/code/Magento/Ui/view/base/web/js/form/element/date.js
```

in the static files:

```
pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/Magento_Ui/js/form/element/date.js
```

The date-element class (object) has method `prepareDateTimeFormats`, where the important option `showsTime` is checked:

```
/**
 * Prepares and converts all date/time formats to be compatible
 * with moment.js library.
 */
prepareDateTimeFormats: function () {
    this.pickerDateTimeFormat = this.options.dateFormat;

    if (this.options.showsTime) {
        this.pickerDateTimeFormat += ' ' + this.options.timeFormat;
    }

    this.pickerDateTimeFormat = utils.normalizeDate(this.pickerDateTimeFormat);

    if (this.dateFormat) {
        this.inputDateFormat = this.dateFormat;
    }

    this.inputDateFormat = utils.normalizeDate(this.inputDateFormat);
    this.outputDateFormat = utils.normalizeDate(this.outputDateFormat);

    this.validationParams.dateFormat = this.outputDateFormat;
}
```

Comment: What is if I want to show only time picker?  @Siarhey

Comment: @RonakChauhan You need another custom element because the `DateTime` element always renders date.

Comment: but how to do that?

Comment: @RonakChauhan You should extend the abstract UI-element and use something like `.timepicker()`

Comment: @RonakChauhan If You don't know how to do that it's better to ask a different question.

Comment: I have already asked the question http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/154140/magento-2-show-timepicker-using-uicomponent

Comment: Could you tell me how to add color picker in ui form ???

Comment: @SameerBhayani Yes, I can. But, please, ask a different question and send me a link.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/189020/magento-2-how-to-add-color-picker-in-ui-form?noredirect=1#comment261743_189020

Comment: @SiarheyUchukhlebau Thanks for your answer, I have a question about your answer,  could you give a help? Thanks. [DateTime UI Component - adjust the timezone](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/198544/datetime-ui-component-adjust-the-timezone)

Comment: Find the solution by myself, your answer has a **wrong timeFormat**, we need change `hh:mm:ss` to `HH:mm:ss` in the UI Componet, otherwise `03:00:00 PM` will became `03:00:00 AM`, lack 12 hours and you **can not save the time of PM** in the  database table.

Comment: @Key Thank you for the investigation, I have updated my answer.

Comment: @SiarheyUchukhlebau this dateTime field is saving wrong date& time (01/12/2193 00:00:00). Console debugging shows it as initial time. Could you pls guide me how to save selected date and time?

Comment: @SachinAgarwal I think you are using different date and time format. Detect a correct one for your store and change this lines: `<item name="dateFormat" xsi:type="string">yyyy-MM-dd</item>
                <item name="timeFormat" xsi:type="string">HH:mm:ss</item>`

Comment: I am not getting that date which I have selected in ui_form. I am getting date in UTC format by default in magento. I want to get actual date which I have selected in ui_form. Please help.

Comment: I am also getting same problem. When the DateTime field is rendered it converts into UTC instead of my default time zone. Can someone help ?

Comment: I have specified the dateFormat in my form element like below.
`<item name="options" xsi:type="array">
      <item name="dateFormat" xsi:type="string">dd.M.yy</item>     
      <item name="showsTime" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
     </item>`
When i checked with `require('uiRegistry').get('index = xxx')` the dateFormat value is not updating as per the configuration value. It still showing the format of the current locale.

Comment: @EmiproTechnologiesPvt.Ltd. To get the time you actually input in UI, you should add:
`<item name="storeTimeZone" xsi:type="string">UTC</item>` into the config array. Although it is stated to be default in the docs, it is only default in JS but earlier overwritten in PHP if not present.

Answer (score 2):

I hope this answer gives some idea about what you miss

I added the UI component of date time field through php (it works fine)

```
$fieldset->addField(
        'event_date',
        'date',
        [
            'name' => 'event_date',
            'label' => __('Date'),
            'title' => __('Date'),
            'required' => true,
            'date_format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd',
            'time_format' => 'hh:mm:ss'
        ]
);
```

[image: easy for your reference]

compare to your xml file all values are present except **date_format** and **time_format** so you can try to set the both value in your xml file

for more details please refer this [full source code](https://github.com/arvind07/productsgrid_magento2/blob/master/Webspeaks/ProductsGrid/Block/Adminhtml/Contact/Edit/Tab/Main.php#L88)

Comment: Can you go through "vendor/magento/module-cms/view/adminhtml/ui_component/cms_block_form.xml" file and let me know how can I integrate the above code.

Comment: How can I change `source` to my custom name ? What requirements are here ?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and I found out that the same issue was reported in the Magento 2 Github repository:

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/23157

And this is the Pull Request with the solution:

https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/31549

It's fixed in Magento 2.4.
So, i made a patch from that Pull Request to apply in previous Magento 2 versions with composer patches:

```
From: Santiago Valveson <https://www.linkedin.com/in/santiago-valveson/>
Subject: [PATCH] Invalid date when timeOnly defined on datetime UIComponent -
 Fixed in the v2.4

---
 view/base/web/js/form/element/date.js         |  9 +++-
 .../js/lib/knockout/bindings/datepicker.js    | 47 +++++++++----------
 2 files changed, 30 insertions(+), 26 deletions(-)

diff --git a/view/base/web/js/form/element/date.js b/view/base/web/js/form/element/date.js
index 22fcdcb..a5447b2 100644
--- a/view/base/web/js/form/element/date.js
+++ b/view/base/web/js/form/element/date.js
@@ -107,6 +107,13 @@ define([
             return this._super().observe(['shiftedValue']);
         },

+        /**
+         * @inheritdoc
+         */
+        getPreview: function () {
+            return this.shiftedValue();
+        },
+
         /**
          * Prepares and sets date/time value that will be displayed
          * in the input field.
@@ -120,7 +127,7 @@ define([
                 if (this.options.showsTime && !this.options.timeOnly) {
                     shiftedValue = moment.tz(value, 'UTC').tz(this.storeTimeZone);
                 } else {
-                    shiftedValue = moment(value, this.outputDateFormat);
+                    shiftedValue = moment(value, this.outputDateFormat, true);
                 }

                 if (!shiftedValue.isValid()) {
diff --git a/view/base/web/js/lib/knockout/bindings/datepicker.js b/view/base/web/js/lib/knockout/bindings/datepicker.js
index 2fab8c2..ff09835 100644
--- a/view/base/web/js/lib/knockout/bindings/datepicker.js
+++ b/view/base/web/js/lib/knockout/bindings/datepicker.js
@@ -7,11 +7,8 @@ define([
     'ko',
     'underscore',
     'jquery',
-    'mage/translate',
-    'mage/calendar',
-    'moment',
-    'mageUtils'
-], function (ko, _, $, $t, calendar, moment, utils) {
+    'mage/translate'
+], function (ko, _, $, $t) {
     'use strict';

     var defaults = {
@@ -46,10 +43,12 @@ define([
                 observable = config;
             }

-            $(el).calendar(options);
+            require(['mage/calendar'], function () {
+                $(el).calendar(options);

-            ko.utils.registerEventHandler(el, 'change', function () {
-                observable(this.value);
+                ko.utils.registerEventHandler(el, 'change', function () {
+                    observable(this.value);
+                });
             });
         },

@@ -62,6 +61,7 @@ define([
          */
         update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
             var config = valueAccessor(),
+                $element = $(element),
                 observable,
                 options = {},
                 newVal;
@@ -75,26 +75,23 @@ define([
                 observable = config;
             }

-            if (_.isEmpty(observable())) {
-                if ($(element).datepicker('getDate')) {
-                    $(element).datepicker('setDate', null);
-                    $(element).blur();
+            require(['moment', 'mage/utils/misc', 'mage/calendar'], function (moment, utils) {
+                if (_.isEmpty(observable())) {
+                    newVal = null;
+                } else {
+                    newVal = moment(
+                        observable(),
+                        utils.convertToMomentFormat(
+                            options.dateFormat + (options.showsTime ? ' ' + options.timeFormat : '')
+                        )
+                    ).toDate();
                 }
-            } else {
-                newVal = moment(
-                    observable(),
-                    utils.convertToMomentFormat(
-                        options.dateFormat + (options.showsTime ? ' ' + options.timeFormat : '')
-                    )
-                ).toDate();

-                if ($(element).datepicker('getDate') == null ||
-                    newVal.valueOf() !== $(element).datepicker('getDate').valueOf()
-                ) {
-                    $(element).datepicker('setDate', newVal);
-                    $(element).blur();
+                if (!options.timeOnly) {
+                    $element.datepicker('setDate', newVal);
+                    $element.blur();
                 }
-            }
+            });
         }
     };
 });
--
2.21.0
```

This is the Magento 2 guide to apply composer patches:

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/comp-mgr/patching/composer.html

This is the code to make it work well (taken from the QA done by Magento to approve the Pull Request
):

```
<field name="start_date">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Start Time</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">date</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">import_profile</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">start_time</item>
                    <item name="options" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="timeOnlyTitle" xsi:type="string">Select Start Time</item>
                    <item name="showsTime" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="timeOnly" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="timeFormat" xsi:type="string">HH:mm:ss</item>
                    <item name="dateFormat" xsi:type="string">yyyy-MM-dd</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
```

---

---

---

Another solution (better to me) is use the type time input:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time

And create a new input template (I choose this way because i couldn't receive the time post param of the original date UI field.

in your module:
Vendor/ModuleName/view/adminhtml/web/template/form/element/time_input.html

```
<input class="admin__control-text" type="time"
       data-bind="
        event: {change: userChanges},
        value: value,
        hasFocus: focused,
        valueUpdate: valueUpdate,
        attr: {
            name: inputName,
            placeholder: placeholder,
            'aria-describedby': noticeId,
            id: uid,
            disabled: disabled,
    }"/>
```

And then, in your form:

```
    <field name="start_date" formElement="input">
        <settings>
            <elementTmpl>Vendor_ModuleName/form/element/time_input</elementTmpl>
            <dataType>text</dataType>
            <dataScope>start_date</dataScope>
            <label translate="true">Start Date</label>
            <validation>
                <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
            </validation>
        </settings>
    </field>
```

And you can standardize the post param in the Save/Validator Controller and the Data Provider  with this:

```
date('H:i', strtotime($this->_request->getParam('opening_time')))
```

Should looks like this:

[Input image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NPGje.png)

[Input image with time select](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVacn.png)