# Magento 2.1 Date Time Calendar

Tags: magento-2.1, admin, calendar

I am using magento calendar in ui component form just like the way it is in the link given here.[Magento 2 - How to add the DateTime UI Component](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/130985/magento-2-how-to-add-the-datetime-ui-component)

It works **fine** when I add a new record, **but** when I edit a record , **the current date and time is shown/picked** by the calendar,indeed the calendar field must show the datetime record saved in the database. Thus when I edit any records , the datetime value gets reset and current datetime is saved in the database.Is this a known bug?. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the problem. It is not a bug.

It should be you set something wrong. I guess it could be the `InstallSchema.php`, when you create date column, notice don't use `'default' => Table::TIMESTAMP_INIT` or `'default' => Table::TIMESTAMP_INIT_UPDATE`.

**Right** example:

```
->addColumn(
    'start_time',
    Table::TYPE_TIMESTAMP,
    null,
    ['nullable' => false]
)
```

**Wrong** example:

```
->addColumn(
    'start_time',
    Table::TYPE_TIMESTAMP,
    null,
    ['nullable' => false, 'default' => Table::TIMESTAMP_INIT_UPDATE]
)
```