# DateTime UI Component - adjust the timezone

Tags: magento-2.1, uicomponent, datetime

I created a time field by the Q&A [Magento 2 - How to add the DateTime UI Component](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/130985/magento-2-how-to-add-the-datetime-ui-component), and I also set the store TimeZone is "**Asia/Shanghai**". But when I click the "<kbd>Go Today</kbd>", it always show the time of **UTC** timezone. How to fix it?

[image: datetime UI Componet]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The timezone is right. The origin of the problem is the **wrong timeFormat** in the answer of [Magento 2 - How to add the DateTime UI Component](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/130985/magento-2-how-to-add-the-datetime-ui-component), We need change `hh:mm:ss` to `HH:mm:ss` in the UI Componet, otherwise `03:00:00 PM`and `03:00:00 AM` will became the same time, lack 12 hours and you **can not save the time of PM** in DB table.

---

Below is the original answer from [Magento 2 - How to add the DateTime UI Component](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/130985/magento-2-how-to-add-the-datetime-ui-component), we need change `<item name="timeFormat" xsi:type="string">hh:mm:ss</item>` to `<item name="timeFormat" xsi:type="string">HH:mm:ss</item>`.

```
<field name="start_date">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Go Live Start Date</item>
            <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">date</item>
            <item name="source" xsi:type="string">page</item>
            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">21</item>
            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">start_date</item>
            <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            </item>
            <item name="options" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="dateFormat" xsi:type="string">yyyy-MM-dd</item>
                <item name="timeFormat" xsi:type="string">hh:mm:ss</item>
                <item name="showsTime" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</field>
```

Comment: I want to store that date which is selected from ui_form.When I select any date from UI form and click on Save then magento will convert that date in UTC format by default. So I am not getting selected date but I got date in UTC format.I want to get that date which selected from ui form. Anyone knows how to solve?

Comment: @EmiproTechnologiesPvt.Ltd. Try set the timezone in Magento admin, the default timezone is UTC.

Comment: @EmiproTechnologiesPvt.Ltd. Have you found the answer? I have same question?

Comment: @EmiproTechnologiesPvt.Ltd.  i also facing same problem have you found something to display only time & save same format to database?

Comment: @RutveeSojitra  i also facing same problem have you found something to display only time & save same format to database?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the store time zone as well otherwise when you select the time its auto-convert to the UTC time zone

```
<item name="storeTimeZone" xsi:type="string">string</item>
```