# Mageno 2 - How to set width of input where I use DateTime picker

Tags: magento2.3, admin, adminform, datepicker

How to set the width of input where I use DateTime picker?

There is a question, which I have reviewed, but it looks like there are no issues.

[Magento 2 - How to add the DateTime UI Component](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/130985/magento-2-how-to-add-the-datetime-ui-component)

[Magento 2 - Date input with time picker](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/252189/magento-2-date-input-with-time-picker)

In my case, I tried different ways to change width of input, where is inserted date and time from DateTime picker, but it is not good.

```
 <field name="start_date">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Start Date</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">date</item>
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">page</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">50</item>
                <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">start_date</item>
                <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                </item>
                <item name="options" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dateFormat" xsi:type="string">yyyy-MM-dd</item>
                    <item name="timeFormat" xsi:type="string">HH:mm:ss</item>
                    <item name="showsTime" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can add a custom class for the specific input field and set CSS for it.

In you `<item name="config" xsi:type="array">` add the below code to add css class

```
<item name="additionalClasses" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="admin__field-my-class" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
</item>
```

now you can add the style to the class.

Hope this help!

Comment: Thank you @Technocracker
It works when I add the following css code:

`.admin__field-datetime input {
    width: 180px !important;
}`

Really, it helps, but look a little bit hackly. 
It is unfortunate that there is no more beautiful solution.