# Tried to implement the datetime picker magento2, but only date is coming

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, datepicker, datetime

I have tried to implement datetime picker in Magento2, only date is coming, datetime picker is not appearing,

```
$eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
            'start_date',
            [
                'type'                    => 'datetime',
                'backend'                 => 'Magento\Catalog\Model\Attribute\Backend\Startdate',
                'frontend'                => '',
                'label'                   => 'start date',
                'note'                    => 'Add start date with 24 hours time format Ex: mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss(05/01/2017 13:10:10)',
                'input'                   => 'date',
                'frontend_class'          => 'starting_date',
                'source'                  => '',
                'global'                  => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                'visible'                 => true,
                'required'                => false,
                'user_defined'            => true,
                'default'                 => '',
                'searchable'              => false,
                'filterable'              => false,
                'comparable'              => false,
                'visible_on_front'        => true,
                'used_in_product_listing' => true,
                'unique'                  => false,
                'apply_to'                => '',
                'is_used_in_grid'         => true,
                'is_visible_in_grid'      => true,
                'is_filterable_in_grid'   => true,
                'group'                   => 'CustomAttribute',
            ]
        );
```

I have tried different option including this [url][1]

[1]: [Magento 2 Create Date with Time attribute for product](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/174840/magento-2-create-date-with-time-attribute-for-product) anyone have done this, it will be awesome to share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same link find the solution [Magento 2 Create Date with Time attribute for product](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/174840/magento-2-create-date-with-time-attribute-for-product)

I have done validation separately for this, because frontend_class is not appearing in the admin side,Magento is validating based on the frontend_class

added these lines in modules Namespace\Modulename\etc\di.xml file

```
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\CatalogEavValidationRules">
      <plugin name="namespace_custom_validation_for_product_attribute" type="Namespace\Modulename\Model\Product\ValidationRules"/>
    </type>
```

and after that we have added validation rules inside Namespace\Modulename\Model\Product\ValidationRules.php

```
<?php

namespace Namespace\Modulename\Model\Product;

use Closure;

class ValidationRules
{

    /**
     * [aroundBuild description]
     * @param  \Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\CatalogEavValidationRules $rulesObject
     * @param  Closure                                                    $proceed
     * @param  \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductAttributeInterface        $attribute
     * @param  array                                                      $data
     * @return array                                                                 [description]
     */
    public function aroundBuild(
        \Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\CatalogEavValidationRules $rulesObject,
        Closure $proceed,
        \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductAttributeInterface $attribute,
        array $data
    ){
        $rules = $proceed($attribute,$data);
        if($attribute->getAttributeCode() == 'attribute_code'){ //my case attibute_code is starting_date
            $validationClasses = explode(' ', $attribute->getFrontendClass());
            foreach ($validationClasses as $class) {
                $rules[$class] = true;
            }
        }

        return $rules;
    }
}
```