# How to show time in product attribute "news_from_date" in admin side in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, admin-panel

How to show time in product attribute "news_from_date" on admin side in Magento 2 give below
[image]

Comment: do you want to modify the default attribute of magento?

Comment: Yes, Just want product[news_from_date] and product[news_to_date] in date time format.

Comment: Got the answer from https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/174840/magento-2-create-date-with-time-attribute-for-product