# Magento 2: custom product attribute add datepicker with time

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, datetime

I am trying to add a datetime custom product attribute but it is showing date only I want to show time as well:
[image]

Here is my install script:

```
<?php
namespace Custom\ProductScheduler\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }
    
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
            'schedule_end',
            [
                'group' => 'Custom Product Scheduler',
                'label' => 'Schedule End Time',
                'type' => 'datetime',
                'input' => 'date',
                'class' => 'validate-date',
                'backend' => 'Custom\ProductScheduler\Model\Entity\Attribute\Backend\Datetime',
                'required' => false,
                'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                'visible' => true,
                'user_defined' => true,
                'default' => '',
                'searchable' => true,
                'filterable' => true,
                'filterable_in_search' => true,
                'visible_in_advanced_search' => true,
                'comparable' => false,
                'visible_on_front' => true,
                'used_in_product_listing' => true,
                'unique' => false
            ]
        );
        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
            'schedule_status',
            [
                'group' => 'Custom Product Scheduler',
                'type' => 'int',
                'backend' => '',
                'frontend' => '',
                'label' => 'Schedule End Status',
                'input' => 'boolean',
                'class' => '',
                'source' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Boolean::class,
                'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
                'visible' => false,
                'required' => false,
                'user_defined' => true,
                'default' => '1',
                'searchable' => true,
                'filterable' => true,
                'comparable' => false,
                'visible_on_front' => true,
                'used_in_product_listing' => true,
                'unique' => false,
                'apply_to' => 'simple'
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the modifiers to render the time with Date.
Please use the reference

[Magento 2 Create Date with Time attribute for product](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/174840/magento-2-create-date-with-time-attribute-for-product)

Hope it works well thanks!!